# Session, Default and Page Cache via redis

Tags: cache, full-page-cache, redis

we are providing a multi store Magento 2 Shop on a multi webnode infrastructure.
Sessions are handled by a redis docker on the DB Server. Is it useful to start new separately docker instances for default and page cache as well or can all be in the same redis-server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We found out that it is not necessary to start multiple instances of redis. You can use different databases instead. Multiple instances only brings you more flexibility on your server environment